# Обновление данных в таблице Oracle C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle, orm, dapper

Есть таблица следующего содержания
[image: таблица 1]

На вход получаю следующее значение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первые 2 ключа в таблице уже есть(условно 0)

Коллекция содержит все остальное описание таблицы, то есть год и 12 значений.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обновить значение в таблице в соответствии с новыми данными.Не нашел в гугле как обновить не примитивные данные, а то есть обновить допустим сразу весь массив по 1 значению и тд.

Бд Oracle

Comment: Я могу составить новый класс в соответствии с моделью таблицы, но возможно ли "ормно" тогда обновить значение в таблице

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134013/can-anybody-help-to-do-bulk-update-using-dapper-orm